# Data get overlaps while using recycler list view in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, recyclerlistview

I try the below code for setting dataProvider but data get overlap initially when the app launch for few microseconds;

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  dataProvider: this.state.dataProvider.cloneWithRows([...nextProps.response_data]),
});
```

Let us know if you have any idea?